# REGEX to match filenname convention

Tags: java, regex

First of all I would like to say thanks to anybody who spend time reading my post.

Well, I am a newbie on the Regex world, I am able to create very basic REGEX but now I want to jump to a more complex one.

The purpose is to match only those filenames wich mets the next naming convention:

The filename should start with a certain char combination, then it should be followed by any 4 numbers, then an underscore. I don't need to take care about the rest of the filename.

There are certain valid combinations for the start of the filename, lets say:

```
ABCD
HIJK
```

are the only valid starting strings for the file name.

For example, the next strings are valid:

`ABCD9403_XXXXXXXXXXXX.XXX` (because it starts with ABCD, then 4 digits and then an underscore)
`HIJK6701_xXxXxX.xXx` (because it starts with HIJK, then 4 digits and then an underscore)

but, the next ones are not valid:

`AMCD6987_xxxxxx.xxx` (because AMCD does not match any of the valid starting strings above: ABCD or HIJK)

`HIJK12F2_xxxxxxx.xxx` (It starts with a valid string (HIJK) but the next part does not contain 4 digits (it contains an F instead))

`ABCD9547-21654sdasd321.321asd` (it matchs one of the valid starting strings and 4 digits but it does not match the underscore.

I am going to code this using Java.

I hope somebody can help me.

All suggestions are well accepted.

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Have you tried to solve the `regex`. If yes then can you show it to us. Also let us know where are you facing the problem.

Comment: Hello @Smit. I am trying to test the suggestions you guys are sent to me. I am trying an online java testers since i am not at my personal computer to code it. However i am not able to match using this, for example: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/

Comment: It works now. I tried with [link]http://myregextester.com/index.php and marked the Java checkbox, it showed me a preview of the code generated internally and I noticed that the "\\" were causing this not to work for me because it was trying to match with the next pattern:

`code`Pattern.compile("^(ABCD|HIJK)\\\\d{4}_");`code`

So I removed one of the two "\" and it worked just fine.

All your suggestions worked prefectly for my case, unfortunatelly I can not mark all as the valid one, so I decided to give my vote to @barnesjd for his time on explaining step by step.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not suggesting anything is wrong with the previous answers. I thought I would include one that works with comments explaining it.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "(?:"       + // Open a "non-capturing" group for our two letter sequences
    "ABCD"      + // The sequence ABCD ...
    "|"         + // OR ...
    "HIJK"      + // the sequence HIJK
    ")"         + // close the group
    "\\d"       + // A digit ...
    "{4}"       + // exactly 4 times
    "_"         + // an underscore
    ".*"          // Anything else.
);

assertTrue(p.matcher("ABCD9403_XXXXXXXXXXXX.XXX").matches());
assertTrue(p.matcher("HIJK6701_xXxXxX.xXx").matches());
assertFalse(p.matcher("AMCD6987_xxxxxx.xxx").matches());
assertFalse(p.matcher("HIJK12F2_xxxxxxx.xxx").matches());
assertFalse(p.matcher("ABCD9547-21654sdasd321.321asd").matches());
```

Answer (score 1):

simply like this:

```
^(ABCD|HIJK)\\d{4}_
```